# How to apply notifications in OnItemClickListener?

Tags: android

I have 3 errors in the code of notification using OnItemClickListener 
i need to apply that when an item is clicked it display notification
here is the code:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Bundle programNum = getIntent().getExtras();
            final String progNum = programNum.getString("ProgNum");
            final String dayNum = programNum.getString("DayNum");

            final List<TouringPrograms> startTime = datasource.getTouringProgramsStartTime(progNum, dayNum);
            final List<TouringPrograms> endTime = datasource.getTouringProgramsEndTime(progNum, dayNum);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgramsList2.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            String body = (String) ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText();
            String title = "Egypt On The Go";
            String time = body + "\n start at:" + startTime.get(position)+ "\n end at:" + endTime.get(position);
            Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.egypt, time, System.currentTimeMillis());
            n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, time, pi);
            n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
            nm.notify(uniqueID, n);
            //String time1 = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();
            //Toast.makeText(this, time1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //finish();

        }});
```

the 3 error :

1.Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgramsList2.class);

2.PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

3.n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, time, pi);

any help please?

Comment: the errors should give you enough information to start investigating

Comment: I guess they are compiler errors, whichever way you are using to compile, you should get some text describing what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Error 1

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgramsList2.class);
```

`this` is an item of type `OnItemClickListener`. You should pass it by declaring `final Context intentContext = (Context) this;` **before** calling `setOnItemClickListener`. Then, use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(intentContext, ProgramsList2.class);
```

Always remember to keep track of your `Context` items; they're important for things like this (`Intent`s, resources, assets, etc.).

#### Error 2

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Exactly the same problem as above. `this` is not of type `Context`. Use the same fix as above.

#### Error 3

```
n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, time, pi);
```

And here, same issue as the above two. You're using `this` when you should be using a `Context`. Same fix as the above two.

#### Summary

Keep track of your `this`s when using [anonymous classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm). And for the future, posting the compile errors (the line of code **as well as** the text of the error itself) is incredibly helpful to those who will provide answers.

Comment: Please consider marking this answer correct, as it will help others who have the same problem solve their issues as well!